# why does swapping the 2d array pointers not work?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to do a simple computation where I need to swap pointers to two arrays. So, I can switch between these two arrays while computing. Following is a simple code in that direction. The first code runs fine if I comment out the code but the second one gives segmentation fault. I don't understand how is the commented code having any effect at all. It is just creating an array. Is there something else wrong in my code that is causing this weird problem?

This runs fine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
/*
    int fixed[1024][1024];

    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1024; j++) {
            fixed[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
*/  

    float o_array[1024][1024];
    float n_array[1024][1024];
    float (*old_array)[1024] = o_array;
    float (*new_array)[1024] = n_array;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1024; j++) {
            old_array[i][j] = 100.0f;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This gives segmentation fault

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int fixed[1024][1024];

    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {      
        for (int j = 0; j < 1024; j++) {
            fixed[i][j] = 1;
        }   
    }
   float o_array[1024][1024];
   float n_array[1024][1024];
   float (*old_array)[1024] = o_array;
   float (*new_array)[1024] = n_array;

   for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 1024; j++) {
           old_array[i][j] = 100.0f;
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's possible you may need to increase the size of the stack in your compiler's options.

Comment: but shouldn't it give some other error if the stack overflowed instead of segmentation fault.

Comment: that seem to solve it! thanks!

Comment: Decided to give a complete answer in case anyone runs into similar problem in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, most compilers set the default memory limit for the stack pretty low (usually around 1mb).

Assuming each float is 4 bytes, a multidimensional array of 1024 units would take up 1024 x 1024 x 4 = 4,194,304 bytes or about 4 Megabytes.

You can increase the size of the stack of your compiler using a command line or in your IDE's build/linker options.

Comment: i checked the stack size in the machine >ulimit -s and it was 8 Mb. So it makes sense why it was working for two arrays but not for three arrays. Since each array occupied 4 MB. Two arrays would take all the stack space...8 mb leaving behind the third array.